# Returning end of string up to certain character using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to accomplish this task:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851568/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-a-string-before-a-certain-character
within the Field Calculator.

I have the below but cannot get it to run.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the syntax from the question, not the answer. Also, the pre-logic code for Python can't reference field names. You also might want to check out `.rpartition()`.

You shouldn't have to use pre-logic at all:

```
Sector = !FolderPath!.rsplit("/")[0]
```

But if you did want to use pre-logic, here's how to do it:

```
def sect(field):
   return field.rsplit("/")[0]
```

---

```
Sector = sect(!FolderPath!)
```

With that being said, if you are splitting pathnames, I encourage you to check out `os.path.split()` instead ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)). It's a lot simpler to deal with pathnames this way and is the more pythonic route.

Edit for slicing:

```
a = [1, "fish", 2, "fish", "red fish", "blue fish"]
a[0] -> 1
a[1] -> "fish"
a[2] -> 2
a[-1] -> "blue fish"
a[0:2] -> [1, "fish"]
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying my overcomplication.  Your suggestions works, but I need it to run from the end of the string.  I added a colon before the 0 but that does not work.

Comment: @mikeLdub Ahh, I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: Or `os.path.dirname()`/`os.path.basename()` if you're only interested in the head/tail of the path, rather than both parts in a tuple.

Comment: @nmpeterson, yes good point! Definitely the better option if you only need one, which OP probably does. I assume he wants the head, but I'm not sure.

Comment: these are all great, but .rsplit is still returning the beginning portion of the string?

Comment: @mikeLdub, you need to look up slicing syntax. The number inside the brackets refers to which number in the list to return. I've edited my post to give a brief overview of slicing. So, you'll probably want to change `[0]` to `[1]`

Comment: got it, I was neglecting the slicing location.  Thanks very much for the help.